# Need Assistance Fixing Rest Response Exception Error in Code During Build

Tags: c#

I was given some code that I was told, by the developer, works just fine. When I go to run Debug, the code won't build and shows an error. I can run the "previously" built code. I can't do anything where I have to put in breakpoints that require a "rebuild"

I spoke with the developer. We went through cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but it has not corrected the issue. The developer insists that the code works fine on his machine and it is a problem on my machine. I went so far as to try the code on another machine and had the same issues.

Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample.JSONDeserializers
{
    public class RESTResponseException : Exception
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
        public RESTResponse Response
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public RESTError Error
        {
            get => Response?.error;
        }
        public RESTResponseException(RESTResponse data, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        {
            Response = data;
            StatusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public RESTResponseException(RESTResponse data, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        : base(message)
        {
            Response = data;
            StatusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public RESTResponseException(RESTResponse data, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
        {
            Response = data;
            StatusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"REST Exception: {Response?.error?.message?.value} (Http Response {StatusCode}) | \n{base.ToString()}";
        }
    }
}
```

The specific section is:

```
public RESTError Error
{
    get => Response?.error;
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I go to build:
[image]

Since the developer indicates this code is correct, I have no idea how to get it to build.

Comment: What version of visual studio was he using and what are you using?

Comment: IIRC expression bodied properties was added in C# 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Response?.error` uses a null conditional operator that only exists in C# 6.0 and above.

Also, expression-bodied members only exists in C# 6.0, and enhanced in 7.0.  Make sure your C# version is at least 7.0

Comment: I'm currently using VS 2015. The version of C# is: 
Visual C# 2015   00322-90002-19666-AA690
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Comment: VS Studio 2105 is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: if it is not a Net Core application, then your Net Framework must be version 4.6. Lower versions does not have null conditional operators.

Comment: I think i found the issue. It looks like C#7 was released in VS 2017 and I'm using VS2015. It would be nice if listing in the "About Visuual Studio" it told you specifically what version of C# was included. It is not obvious that Visual C# 2015 is C#6.